# Trouble with a line intersection algorithm

Tags: line, intersection, .net

So to put this in perspective, I have a DXF file, I parsed the lines from the DXF file and I have to create polygons from those lines. I decided to save the created polygons from those lines to SVGs on my local machine. Now, the thing is there are a lot of invalid polygons (polygons which lines intersect one another) and I want to reject those polygons, I've been trying to write logic in a single program.cs file and for now I had no luck. Can you see if I might have missed something:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SVGIntersections
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string svg1 = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""no""?>
                            <svg width=""100%"" height=""100%"" version=""1.1"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" viewBox=""476197.89 4765468.52 20.429999999993015 21.580000000074506"">
                            <polygon points=""
                            476198.11,4765470.84 
                            476210.74,4765468.52 
                            476218.32,4765487.72 
                            476206.49,4765490.1 
                            476204.85,4765486.32 
                            476204.85,4765486.32 
                            476197.89,4765470.34 
                            ""
                            style=""fill:blue;stroke:black;stroke-width:2;fill-opacity:0.6;stroke-opacity:1"" />
                            </svg>
                            ";

            string svg2 = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""no""?>
                            <svg width=""100%"" height=""100%"" version=""1.1"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" viewBox=""476198.11 4765466.28 36.73000000003958 23.8199999993667"">
                            <polygon points=""
                            476230.84,4765485.2 
                            476218.32,4765487.72 
                            476206.49,4765490.1 
                            476204.85,4765486.32 
                            476222.93,4765466.28 
                            476234.84,4765484.39 
                            ""
                            style=""fill:blue;stroke:black;stroke-width:2;fill-opacity:0.6;stroke-opacity:1"" />
                            </svg>
                            ";

            string svg3 = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""no""?>
                            <svg width=""100%"" height=""100%"" version=""1.1"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" viewBox=""476218.32 4765465.54 32.0800000000163 56.080000000074506"">
                            <polygon points=""
                            476234.84,4765484.39 
                            476230.84,4765485.2 
                            476226.96,4765465.54 
                            476250.4,4765521.62 
                            ""
                            style=""fill:blue;stroke:black;stroke-width:2;fill-opacity:0.6;stroke-opacity:1"" />
                            </svg>
                            ";

            string svg4 = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""no""?>
                            <svg width=""100%"" height=""100%"" version=""1.1"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" viewBox=""476566.86 4765747.21 13.290000000037253 14.28000000026077"">
                            <polygon points=""
                            476575.71,4765748.43 
                            476571.21,4765749.69 
                            476576.2,4765750.34 
                            476576.6,4765751.92 
                            476577.12,4765753.95 
                            476578.82,4765760.5 
                            476574.48,4765761.49 
                            476572.64,4765754.97 
                            476580.15,4765747.21 
                            476571.21,4765749.69 
                            ""
                            style=""fill:blue;stroke:black;stroke-width:2;fill-opacity:0.6;stroke-opacity:1"" />
                            </svg>
                            ";

            bool isValid1 = SVGParser.HasIntersectingLines(svg1);
            bool isValid2 = SVGParser.HasIntersectingLines(svg2);
            bool isValid3 = SVGParser.HasIntersectingLines(svg3);
            bool isValid4 = SVGParser.HasIntersectingLines(svg4);

            Console.WriteLine($"SVG 1 is valid: {isValid1}");
            Console.WriteLine($"SVG 2 is valid: {isValid2}");
            Console.WriteLine($"SVG 3 is valid: {isValid3}");
            Console.WriteLine($"SVG 4 is valid: {isValid4}");
        }
    }

    public static class SVGParser
    {
        public static bool HasIntersectingLines(string svgData)
        {
            List<Line2D> lines = ParseSVG(svgData);
            return CheckForIntersections(lines);
        }

        private static List<Line2D> ParseSVG(string svgData)
        {
            List<Line2D> lines = new List<Line2D>();
            string pattern = @"<polygon points=""(.*?)""";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(svgData, pattern);

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                string pointsData = match.Groups[1].Value;
                string[] points = pointsData.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\n', '\r', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                for (int i = 0; i < points.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    string[] coords1 = points[i].Split(',');
                    string[] coords2 = points[i + 1].Split(',');

                    if (coords1.Length == 2 && coords2.Length == 2)
                    {
                        double x1 = double.Parse(coords1[0]);
                        double y1 = double.Parse(coords1[1]);
                        double x2 = double.Parse(coords2[0]);
                        double y2 = double.Parse(coords2[1]);

                        lines.Add(new Line2D(new XYPoints(x1, y1), new XYPoints(x2, y2)));
                    }
                }
            }

            return lines;
        }

        private static bool CheckForIntersections(List<Line2D> lines)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < lines.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (lines[i].intersectsLine(lines[j]))
                    {
                        return true; // Intersection found
                    }
                }
            }
            return false; // No intersections found
        }
    }

    public class Line2D
    {
        public double X1 = 0;
        public double X2 = 0;
        public double Y1 = 0;
        public double Y2 = 0;

        public XYPoints P1;
        public XYPoints P2;

        public Line2D(XYPoints p1, XYPoints p2)
        {
            P1 = p1;
            P2 = p2;
            X1 = p1.X;
            X2 = p2.X;
            Y1 = p1.Y;
            Y2 = p2.Y;
        }

        public double getX1()
        {
            return X1;
        }
        public double getX2()
        {
            return X2;
        }
        public double getY1()
        {
            return Y1;
        }
        public double getY2()
        {
            return Y2;
        }

        public XYPoints getP1()
        {
            return P1;
        }

        public XYPoints getP2()
        {
            return P2;
        }

        public bool intersectsLine(Line2D comparedLine)
        {
            if (X2 == comparedLine.X1 && Y2 == comparedLine.Y1)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (X1 == comparedLine.X2 && Y1 == comparedLine.Y2)
            {
                return false;
            }
            double firstLineSlopeX, firstLineSlopeY, secondLineSlopeX, secondLineSlopeY;

            firstLineSlopeX = X2 - X1;
            firstLineSlopeY = Y2 - Y1;

            secondLineSlopeX = comparedLine.getX2() - comparedLine.getX1();
            secondLineSlopeY = comparedLine.getY2() - comparedLine.getY1();

            double s, t;
            s = (-firstLineSlopeY * (X1 - comparedLine.getX1()) + firstLineSlopeX * (getY1() - comparedLine.getY1())) / (-secondLineSlopeX * firstLineSlopeY + firstLineSlopeX * secondLineSlopeY);
            t = (secondLineSlopeX * (getY1() - comparedLine.getY1()) - secondLineSlopeY * (getX1() - comparedLine.getX1())) / (-secondLineSlopeX * firstLineSlopeY + firstLineSlopeX * secondLineSlopeY);

            if (s >= 0 && s <= 1 && t >= 0 && t <= 1)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false; // No collision
        }


        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (X1 * 1000 + X2 * 1000 + Y1 * 1000 + Y2 * 1000).GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return (obj.GetHashCode() == this.GetHashCode());
        }
    }

    public class XYPoints
    {
        public double X;
        public double Y;

        public XYPoints(double x, double y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

svg1 and svg2 should return true for valid polygon and svg3 and svg 4 should return false.